# Mystery gaps in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the snippet below, there are gaps above and beneath '`main`' area which suppose to be an empty cells with the same height as the grid cells. Also there is an empty space at the very bottom.

I've tried setting `grid-auto-flow` to different values, but there is no effect except for the very bottom gap when it set to `column`.

What causes that? and how to fix it?

```css
.header {
    grid-area: hd;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: ft;
}
.content {
    grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sd;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "hd hd ft"
      "sd . ft"
      "sd main ft"
      "sd . ft";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

First, let's see the gaps (they don't appear in many cases):

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd ft" "sd . ft" "sd main ft" "sd . ft";
}

.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}

.content {
  grid-area: main;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sd;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

What you're seeing is the rendering of `&nbsp;` ([non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) characters in the HTML code.

[image]

As white space characters, they're invisible, which makes them hard to detect. But once you remove them, the layout works as expected.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd ft" "sd . ft" "sd main ft" "sd . ft";
}

.header {
  grid-area: hd;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: ft;
}

.content {
  grid-area: main;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sd;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**Lastly, why doesn't the faulty layout display in many cases?**

When you copy HTML code as rendered on a web page (e.g., copy the code directly from the question), the `&nbsp;` characters, being HTML code, have already been rendered. So only plain (collapsible) white space gets copied and the layout will appear to be working fine.

Also, if you copy the HTML code from some code editors in some browsers (e.g., the Stack Snippet editor on Edge), the `&nbsp;` characters don't get copied, either. I needed to copy the code from the jsFiddle editor in Chrome to finally see the problem.

Also, if you hit the "Tidy" button in the editor using the original code, spaces will be added between the lines.

Comment: Great explanation! And I thought I'm seeing things, because the white spaces appeard in codepen source but not in my site.

Comment: I also would replace `grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);` with `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` to complete your answer, so the periods rendered as a real empty cells. Thanks @Michael_B

Answer (score 2):

**I tested the code on Chrome and Firefox and the result was **

[image]

[image]

Always add the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration to your HTML documents, so that the browser knows what type of document to expect.

```css
.header {
    grid-area: hd;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: ft;
}
.content {
    grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sd;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "hd hd ft"
      "sd . ft"
      "sd main ft"
      "sd . ft";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 
  </head>

<body>




<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is already set to <doctype html>, the prolem still exists. I did try safari and chrome, same problem.

Answer (score -1):

The empty cells have to be inserted, you'll not get it by default, just adding the HTML and body tag fixed the bottom gap issue:

```css
.header {
    grid-area: hd;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: ft;
}
.content {
    grid-area: main;
}
.sidebar {
    grid-area: sd;
}
.empty-cell1 {
    grid-area: ec1;
}
.empty-cell2 {
    grid-area: ec2;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.wrapper {
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "hd hd ft"
      "sd ec1 ft"
      "sd main ft"
      "sd ec2 ft";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 
  </head>

<body>




<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    <div class="empty-cell1"></div>
    <div class="empty-cell2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a workaround. All documents I've seen are using periods only.